# Task.WhenAll write to blob fail to close or complete

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

When writing about 200 300k blobs to blob storage using Task.WhenAll(List) the writes hang / take significantly longer than performing each in order.

I'm running the process in a function app.

Doesn't work

```
private async Task WriteToBlobAsync(List<DataSeries> allData)
        {
            int blobCount = 0;
            List<Task> blobWriteTasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach(DataSeries series in allData)
            {
                blobCount++;
                string seriesInJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(series);
                blobWriteTasks.Add(_destinationBlobStore.WriteBlobAsync(seriesInJson, series.SaveName));
                //await _destinationBlobStore.WriteBlobAsync(seriesInJson, series.SaveName);
                if (blobCount % 100 == 0)
                {
                    _flightSummaryDoc.AddLog($"{blobCount} Blobs Complete");
                    _log.Info($"{blobCount} Blobs Complete");
                }
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(blobWriteTasks.ToArray());
        }
```

Works significantly faster (but shouldn't)

```
private async Task WriteToBlobAsync(List<DataSeries> allData)
        {
            int blobCount = 0;
            List<Task> blobWriteTasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach(DataSeries series in allData)
            {
                blobCount++;
                string seriesInJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(series);
                //blobWriteTasks.Add(_destinationBlobStore.WriteBlobAsync(seriesInJson,series.SaveName));
                await _destinationBlobStore.WriteBlobAsync(seriesInJson, series.SaveName);
                if(blobCount % 100 == 0)
                {
                    _flightSummaryDoc.AddLog($"{blobCount} Blobs Complete");
                    _log.Info($"{blobCount} Blobs Complete");
                }
            }
            //await Task.WhenAll(blobWriteTasks.ToArray());
        }
```

Comment: What does `WriteBlobAsync` look like?

Comment: I don't know what the maximum number of connections should be, but I'm almost positive the problem is you're hammering your server with a bunch of concurrent requests. If I were you, I would try only keeping only a few requests open at once. Maybe add new requests only after old ones complete? Maybe await when the count of uncompleted tasks is 3-5. I'm not sure if that's the best way to do that. Perhaps this warrants a new SO post on how to best space out concurrent requests. But certainly don't try 200 at once.

Answer (score 1):

It's slowing down and failing because it can't handle 200 concurrent requests.

Consider using `SemaphorSlim` to use its built-in throttling mechanism and limit the concurrent requests to a more reasonable number.

See this post: [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations/10810730#10810730)

Comment: Interesting.  So 200 is too many, how many can I safely configure my semaphor to?  What is the bottleneck?

Comment: @A.Rowan I'm not really sure, you'd have to check the blob provider documentation. However, my shoot-from-the-hip guess would be somewhere in the range of 3-10. You don't gain much from using a high number of concurrent connections because it just means that each one goes slower. If I were you I'd just benchmark it and see what sort of number works best in practice.